# Laravel 5.4 does not supports PHP version 7.4.5

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, logic

I am working on the application which is built on the laravel 5.4 framework. I have installed the latest version of PHP. which is 
**PHP Version 7.4.5**
Actually I would like to know does PHP 7.4.5 supports laravel 5.4 app if no then why? and how can I downgrade the PHP version?

Also I am getting the error in php logs files ( [2020-05-15 12:37:08] local.ERROR:

> ErrorException: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\carehalo_mini\app\Helpers.php:392 )

Also, you can check out the code in the given screenshot [Helpers.php:392 lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPCyE.png)

Comment: I have also tried composer update command but nothing works.

Comment: In php 7.4 trying to access null, bool & etc. as array will throw this notice. So your $admin is probably null. Laravel 5.4 probably don't support 100% php 7.4, but I didn't find  correct info about this.

Comment: If you want to find out, just check the documentation... https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#server-requirements . According to that, it will run on anything from PHP 5.6.4 upwards.

Comment: Of course if the error is coming from code you have written in the application, rather than in the Laravel framework itself, then that's a different, separate problem.

Comment: @katsarov well great answer thanks for the knowledge man

Comment: @ADyson well yeah actually it was code problem, not about versions/framework

Answer (score 1):

`app\Helpers.php` this sounds like something part of the app you have and not related to Laravel. My best guess is that Laravel won't have any problems running on 7.4, but the same does not apply for the code written in the app. And of course, best thing to do would be to upgrade your Laravel version to at least 6 regardless of working or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) but actually I need to follow boss instructions so that's why I cannot change anything on my own :/

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your Error by changing line 392 to:

`if(empty($admin) || ($admin->token != Session::get('token'))`

Comment: since, as the error states, the value of `$admin` is `null`, it's unclear how this is supposed to help? If something is null, then by definition you can't access anything on it, whether array offsets or class properties. The solution is going to be to find out why that object is null in the first place, when clearly it's not expected to be.

Comment: I edited my answer. My bad, that I was expecting that the $admin is existing.

Comment: yo yo thanks bro its work :) (y) if($admin->token != ... this one

Comment: ok maybe this will stop the error, but will the code behave correctly afterwards? Likely it will just cause another problem later on, if it's expecting a token value or something, or for the $admin value to be available at another time. If it's not supposed to be null, then the solution is to debug it to see why it's now coming out as null when it never did previously.

Comment: @ADyson yes, but we cant know the whole logic based on few lines. We can fix direct problems, which this solution is fixing. Now it is on the Mujtaba to make it correct.

Comment: @Autista_z this way also works thanks for the help :)